# Client should send a message automatically without user interaction

Tags: go

I have client-server written in Go. The server sends "hello" every 5 seconds and I want the client to respond "I'm OK". I can see the "hello" output at the client side. I want the client to send the message automatically. At the client side I have:

```
conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8181")
for {
    message, _ := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Print(message)
    conn.Write([]byte("I'm OK"))
}
```

But the message is sent only after client user presses "enter" but I need it to be automatic.

Comment: Have you tried  `conn.Write([]byte("I'm OK\n"))`?

Comment: Wow, I added the `\n` and now it works! thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Create a single bufio.Reader outside of the loop to avoid discarding buffered data read from the connection.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Ok, thank you